# Как убрать отступ снизу у последнего элемента li-карточки?

Tags: css

Нужно убрать нижний отступ у послденго li - карточки.

Не помогает:

```
.content__list:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это тоже не подойдет, потому что может быть только 3 li элемента, в таком случае кнопки "Показать еще" не будет, из-за этого отступ схлопывается у 2-х последних элементов:

```
.content__list-item:nth-last-child(2) {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

[image: 3 элемента li , кнопки нет]

Код со страницы:

```css
body{
 background-color: #1b1919; 
}

.button {
  display: flex;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 10px;
  width: 194px;
  min-height: 34px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: inherit;  
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: inherit;
  background-color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.content__details {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  gap: 26px;
  min-width: 399px;
}

.content__accent {
  color: #545050;
}

.content__list {
  position: relative;
  height: 298px;
  overflow-y: auto; /* auto - появляется скролл */
}

.content__list-item {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.content__list-item:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.content__video-card-description-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 6px;
}

.content__card-link {
  display: block;
  width: 399px;
  margin: 2px;
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.content__card-link:active {
  background-color: #545050;
}

.content__card-link:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.content__card-link:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.content__card-link:focus-visible {
  outline: 1px solid #fff;
}

.content__card-link_current {
  background-color: #545050;
}

.content__video-card {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.content__video-card-title {    
    font-family: Oswald, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: 100%;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.content__video-card-description {
  font-family: inherit;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: 16.2px; 
}

.content__video-card-thumbnail {
  width: 194px;
  height: 103px;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
}

.more-button {
  width: 399px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="content__list"> 
     <li class="content__list-item">
        <a href="#0" class="content__card-link content__card-link_current" id="32">
          <article class="content__video-card">
            <div class="content__video-card-description-container">
              <h2 class="content__video-card-title">Белгород</h2>
              <p class="content__video-card-description">ночной Белгород</p>
            </div>
            <img src="https://v-content.practicum-team.ru/uploads/Belgorod_Noch_mp4_thumb_8e63aba026.png" alt="ночной Белгород" class="content__video-card-thumbnail">
          </article>
        </a>
      </li>
    
      <li class="content__list-item">
        <a href="#0" class="content__card-link" id="33">
          <article class="content__video-card">
            <div class="content__video-card-description-container">
              <h2 class="content__video-card-title">Адлер</h2>
              <p class="content__video-card-description">Адлер утром</p>
            </div>
            <img src="https://v-content.practicum-team.ru/uploads/Adler_Utro_mp4_thumb_aa34fe8f1a.png" alt="Адлер утром" class="content__video-card-thumbnail">
          </article>
        </a>
      </li>
    
      <li class="content__list-item">
        <a href="#0" class="content__card-link" id="34">
          <article class="content__video-card">
            <div class="content__video-card-description-container">
              <h2 class="content__video-card-title">Воронеж</h2>
              <p class="content__video-card-description">Воронеж днем</p>
            </div>
            <img src="https://v-content.practicum-team.ru/uploads/Voronezh_Den_mp4_thumb_f15c5913ca.png" alt="Воронеж днем" class="content__video-card-thumbnail">
          </article>
        </a>
      </li>
    
      <li class="content__list-item">
        <a href="#0" class="content__card-link" id="35">
          <article class="content__video-card">
            <div class="content__video-card-description-container">
              <h2 class="content__video-card-title">Дубай</h2>
              <p class="content__video-card-description">Утро в Дубае</p>
            </div>
            <img src="https://v-content.practicum-team.ru/uploads/Dubaj_Utro_mp4_thumb_531e868753.png" alt="Утро в Дубае" class="content__video-card-thumbnail">
          </article>
        </a>
      </li>
    
      <li class="content__list-item">
        <a href="#0" class="content__card-link" id="36">
          <article class="content__video-card">
            <div class="content__video-card-description-container">
              <h2 class="content__video-card-title">Зеленоградск</h2>
              <p class="content__video-card-description">Дневной Зеленоградск</p>
            </div>
            <img src="https://v-content.practicum-team.ru/uploads/Zelenogradsk_Den_mp4_thumb_308d520d6c.png" alt="Дневной Зеленоградск" class="content__video-card-thumbnail">
          </article>
        </a>
      </li>    
      <li><button class="button more-button">Показать еще</button></li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант с использованием [:has](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/:has)

Поддержка браузерами ~ 87.53% https://caniuse.com/css-has

```
.content__list:has(.more-button) .content__list-item:nth-last-of-type(2)
```

Пример

```css
body {
  background-color: #1b1919;
}

.button {
  display: flex;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 10px;
  width: 194px;
  min-height: 34px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: inherit;
  background-color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.content__details {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  gap: 26px;
  min-width: 399px;
}

.content__accent {
  color: #545050;
}

.content__list {
  position: relative;
  height: 298px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  /* auto - появляется скролл */
}

.content__list-item {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.content__list:has(.more-button) .content__list-item:nth-last-of-type(2){
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.content__video-card-description-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 6px;
}

.content__card-link {
  display: block;
  width: 399px;
  margin: 2px;
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.content__card-link:active {
  background-color: #545050;
}

.content__card-link:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.content__card-link:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.content__card-link:focus-visible {
  outline: 1px solid #fff;
}

.content__card-link_current {
  background-color: #545050;
}

.content__video-card {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.content__video-card-title {
  font-family: Oswald, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: 100%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.content__video-card-description {
  font-family: inherit;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: 16.2px;
}

.content__video-card-thumbnail {
  width: 194px;
  height: 103px;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
}

.more-button {
  width: 399px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="content__list">
  <li class="content__list-item">
    <a href="#0" class="content__card-link content__card-link_current" id="32">
      <article class="content__video-card">
        <div class="content__video-card-description-container">
          <h2 class="content__video-card-title">Белгород</h2>
          <p class="content__video-card-description">ночной Белгород</p>
        </div>
        <img src="https://v-content.practicum-team.ru/uploads/Belgorod_Noch_mp4_thumb_8e63aba026.png" alt="ночной Белгород" class="content__video-card-thumbnail">
      </article>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li class="content__list-item">
    <a href="#0" class="content__card-link" id="33">
      <article class="content__video-card">
        <div class="content__video-card-description-container">
          <h2 class="content__video-card-title">Адлер</h2>
          <p class="content__video-card-description">Адлер утром</p>
        </div>
        <img src="https://v-content.practicum-team.ru/uploads/Adler_Utro_mp4_thumb_aa34fe8f1a.png" alt="Адлер утром" class="content__video-card-thumbnail">
      </article>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li class="content__list-item">
    <a href="#0" class="content__card-link" id="34">
      <article class="content__video-card">
        <div class="content__video-card-description-container">
          <h2 class="content__video-card-title">Воронеж</h2>
          <p class="content__video-card-description">Воронеж днем</p>
        </div>
        <img src="https://v-content.practicum-team.ru/uploads/Voronezh_Den_mp4_thumb_f15c5913ca.png" alt="Воронеж днем" class="content__video-card-thumbnail">
      </article>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li class="content__list-item">
    <a href="#0" class="content__card-link" id="35">
      <article class="content__video-card">
        <div class="content__video-card-description-container">
          <h2 class="content__video-card-title">Дубай</h2>
          <p class="content__video-card-description">Утро в Дубае</p>
        </div>
        <img src="https://v-content.practicum-team.ru/uploads/Dubaj_Utro_mp4_thumb_531e868753.png" alt="Утро в Дубае" class="content__video-card-thumbnail">
      </article>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li class="content__list-item">
    <a href="#0" class="content__card-link" id="36">
      <article class="content__video-card">
        <div class="content__video-card-description-container">
          <h2 class="content__video-card-title">Зеленоградск</h2>
          <p class="content__video-card-description">Дневной Зеленоградск</p>
        </div>
        <img src="https://v-content.practicum-team.ru/uploads/Zelenogradsk_Den_mp4_thumb_308d520d6c.png" alt="Дневной Зеленоградск" class="content__video-card-thumbnail">
      </article>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li><button class="button more-button">Показать еще</button></li>
</ul>

<br>

<hr>

<br>

<ul class="content__list">
  <li class="content__list-item">
    <a href="#0" class="content__card-link content__card-link_current" id="32">
      <article class="content__video-card">
        <div class="content__video-card-description-container">
          <h2 class="content__video-card-title">Белгород</h2>
          <p class="content__video-card-description">ночной Белгород</p>
        </div>
        <img src="https://v-content.practicum-team.ru/uploads/Belgorod_Noch_mp4_thumb_8e63aba026.png" alt="ночной Белгород" class="content__video-card-thumbnail">
      </article>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="content__list-item">
    <a href="#0" class="content__card-link" id="33">
      <article class="content__video-card">
        <div class="content__video-card-description-container">
          <h2 class="content__video-card-title">Адлер</h2>
          <p class="content__video-card-description">Адлер утром</p>
        </div>
        <img src="https://v-content.practicum-team.ru/uploads/Adler_Utro_mp4_thumb_aa34fe8f1a.png" alt="Адлер утром" class="content__video-card-thumbnail">
      </article>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Может проще делать отступ сверху и для первого элемента убирать отступ? Тогда `:has` непонадобится.

Answer (score 1):

"last-child" - это последний элемент в родителе, а у вас последний элемент в списке это кнопка. Если вам нужен последний элемент из "content__list-item" - попробуйте "last-of-type".(кнопку из li нужно будет достать)